# android spinner

Tags: android, spinner

In my app i make the app fullscreen. But when i click on the spinner the hidden notification bar gets visible for fraction of seconds. It is not happening with all the spinners in my app. But where the spinner contains a large scroll list.

i used the following code.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> aisle_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Aisle_Number);
 Spinner spAisle=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.AisleSpinner);
 spAisle.setAdapter(aisle_Adapter);
```

is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You try to hide the notification bar by writing code in the class file itself. Refer the link below: http://sree.cc/google/android/hiding-the-notification-bar-and-title-bar-in-android

Comment: yes. i found that its an open issue in android 2.1 os. please refer      http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674